# PHPMailer como receber respostas de que o e-mail não foi entregue

Tags: php, phpmailer, smtp

Acredito que as pessoas não estão entendendo o que quero saber.

Na verdade já até arrumei uma solução, que estou testando e vou descreve-la aqui.

Não quero saber se o e-mail foi enviado com sucesso e nem saber se o destinatário abriu o e-mail. Isso já faço no sistema que estou desenvolvendo e funciona perfeitamente bem.

O que preciso saber é se o e-mail foi aceite pelo servidor do destinatário ou se foi recusado. Assim marcando-o como um e-mail errado e não válido.

Comecei a usar este extensão do PHPMailer para fazer o serviço (PHPMailer-BMH : Bounce Mail Handler que vai verificar essa situação e me dar um callback. Como falei, ainda estou testando e assim que obter resultados possitivos, volto para demonstrar a solução que fiz.

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou precisando da ajuda de vocês. A questão é a seguinte: Estou criando para uma empresa um sistema de envio de e-mail automatizado. Ele pega uma lista de clientes que está no banco de dados e manda e-mails. Sem problemas.

A lista de clientes é atualizada todos os meses, com novos clientes, via csv. Eles geram esse csv do sistema deles e me mandam, eu trabalho ele aqui e faço a inserção no banco de dados. blz.

A questão é que tenho muitos e-mail que não são válidos, por vários motivos, desde estarem mal escritos, por não existirem mais e etc. E sempre que eu faço a importação novamente, lá estão eles novamente.

Queria saber se existe alguma maneira de pegar a resposta do envio do e-mail que ele não foi entregue, assim poderia usar o e-mail em questão para ativar uma flag, tipo BlackList para quando for fazer a nova importação o sistema pulasse esse ou até na hora do envio faço uma verificação dessa flag.

Uso o PHPmailer para o envio e um servidor local, mas posso passar o sistema para um servidor online com domínio.

Como posso pegar essa resposta que o e-mail não foi entregue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Existe uma forma de verificar se o destinatário abriu o email. Eu uso esse recurso para excluir emails que não abrem os emails enviados.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no serviço SES da AWS.

Answer (score -1):

Com o `if ($mail->send()) {` você pode verificar se ele foi enviado ao protocolo com sucesso, mas se ele foi entregue ou não, ai acho que já é com o próprio protocolo, teria que verificar no e-mail de autenticação se retornou alguma mensagem ou não.